# Sum rows with same identification-number and sort by custom order

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have the following table structure for the table "products":

```
id    amount    number
1     10        M6545
2     32        M6424
3     32        M6545
4     49        M6412
...   ...       ...
```

I want to select the sum of amounts of all rows with the same number. The rows with the same number should be summed up to one sum. That means:

> M6545 -> Sum 42
>
> M6424 -> Sum 32
>
> M6421 -> Sum 49

My query looks like the following and still does not work:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as SumAm FROM products WHERE number IN ('M6412', 'M6545')
```

I want to find a way where I can only select the sum ordered by the numbers in the "IN" statement. That means, the result table should look like:

```
SumAm
49
42
```

The sums should not be ordered in some way. It should match the order of numbers in the `IN` clause.

Comment: try to add `group by number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't order by results based directly on the order of the `IN` clause.
What you can do is something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as SumAm 
FROM products 
WHERE number IN ('M6412', 'M6545')
GROUP BY number -- You must group by to get a row for each number
ORDER BY CASE number 
             WHEN 'M6412' THEN 1
             WHEN 'M6545' THEN 2
         END
```

Of course, the more items you have in your `IN` clause the more cumbersome this query will get. Therefor another solution might be more practical - joining to a table variable instead of using `IN`:

```
DECLARE @Numbers AS TABLE 
(
    sort int identity(1,1), -- this will hold the order of the inserted values 
    number varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY -- enforce unique values
);

INSERT INTO @Numbers (number) VALUES
('M6412'), 
('M6545')

SELECT SUM(amount) as SumAm 
FROM products As p
JOIN numbers As n ON p.Number = n.Number
-- number and sort have a 1 - 1 relationship, 
-- so it's safe to group by it instead of by number
GROUP BY n.sort 
ORDER BY n.sort
```

Answer (score 2):

use `group by` number

```
SELECT number, SUM(amount) as SumAm FROM products     
--WHERE number IN ('M6412', 'M6545') i think you dont need where clause
group by number
```

But if you want just for 'M6412', 'M6545' then you need where clause that you showed in your 2nd output sample

Comment: I need the select with the where clause. The problem is, if I have a where clause like `WHERE number in ('M6545', 'M6412')` it sorts the sums for some reason that the result set starts with the sum for the number M6412. I want to avoid that.

Comment: @Bob you can use order by for that

Answer (score 1):

Use group by and aggregation

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as SumAm FROM products
WHERE number IN ('M6412', 'M6545') 
group by number
```

Comment: Is there a way to select only the sum without number?

Comment: @Bob, remove number column from select list

Comment: @Bob in that what would be your output?

Comment: Tested this solution. The problem is, it sorts the solution set based on the numbers. Therefore, it does not match the order in the In-Brace.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is non-sense... this is not how `IN` is designed to work. Having said that, the following will give you the result in the desired order:

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM (VALUES
    ('M6545', 1),
    ('M6412', 2)
) AS va(number, sortorder)
INNER JOIN sumam ON va.number = sumam.number
GROUP BY va.number, va.sortorder
ORDER BY va.sortorder
```

It is somewhat better than writing a CASE statement when you would need to add a WHEN condition for each number.